# Bundle fields into an array?

Tags: laravel

I have a variety of fields on my model, for example:

- price
- width
- height

... + 10 more

I wish to bundle these up into an array.

I've considered doing a "stats" `accessor` and appending it. But with this approach the original fields mentioned above will also be "sent" along with my new "stats" array.

Is there a better way to bundle parts of a model up into an array?

Note, that I only need the `stats` array on certain requests.

Comment: you can hide above fields using the ``$hidden`` property  if you don't want in response. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

Comment: You can create Api Resource for specific field to be appended.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [API Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-resources). Resources allow you to return only the fields you want, and the ability to transform them before returning.

```
php artisan make:resource StatsResource
```

##### Your controller

```php
use App\Http\Resources\StatsResource

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $stats = Stats::all();

        return [
            'stats' => StatsResource::make($stats);
        ]
    }
}
```

##### StatsResource

```php
class StatsResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'price' => $this->price / 100,
            'width' => $this->width,
            'height' => $this->height,
            ....
        ];
    }
}
```

You can also return collections as arrays. Here's an example using Spatie's Laravel Media Library

##### UserController

```php
$users = User::where('status', 'something')->with('media')->get();

return [
    'users' => MediaResource::collection($users),
]
```

##### MediaResource

```php
class MediaResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'photo' => $this->getTemporaryUrl(now()->addHour(), 'thumb'),
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: So I could make a Stats resource, even though there is no corresponding model?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, I'm thinking you could also just create a Trait and pass your data to that: `return StatsTrait::makeArray($items);`

Comment: You can pass a collection to a resource, so I'm thinking you can make your array a collection and pass that through. `StatsResource::make(collect($stats));` But this is just a hunch as I've never tried it.